How to view all market filled order for a trading pair using coinbase API
I'm currently using coinbase API (Python) to try out a trading strategy I had in my mind.
I have been dabbling with the SDK but with no results, so I need some advise.
Does coinbase python SDK have any way to:

View all historical transaction details for a trading pair?
Current filled orders which includes volume, price transacted & timestamp (Existing participants not just for my account)?


Please read [ask]. There's no programming question, as written - just general info queries.

Any luck? I have no clue how the thing works, and there documentation isn't easy to use (for me, at least).

I think it's not very quant friendly. Under institution API, but i think you would have to pay for data or something. Binance API is much easier to navigate but I'm not sure if deployment from certain countries are allowed (otherwise, it's gg to be challenging).
